# Independence of variables

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

I have an odd question. Suppose $z$ is a function of $x,y$. That is, $z$ is dependent on $x,y$. This can be expressed by writing $z=f(x,y)$. This can in turn be written as $F(x,y,z)=0$, where $F(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z$. My question is, can we call $F$ a function of three independent variables $x,y,z$?. 
On one hand it feels wrong because I know that $z$ depends on $x,y$. On the other hand, I can always define the function $F$ in the above manner regardless of any existing relationship among the three variables. 
Where am I thinking wrong? Should I use another variable to define $F$ instead of $z$?

Comment: $F$ is indeed a function of three independent variables. $z$ does not become dependent on $x, y$ until you demand that $F(x, y, z) = 0$. And even then, it is up to you (with some limitations) to decide whether $z$ depends on $x, y$, or $y$ depends on $x, z$, or $x$ depends on $y, z$.

Comment: Suppose I write $F(x,y,z)=0$. After writing that, do I lose the privilege to call $F$ a function of three independent variables $x,y,z$?